# Facebook Business SDK for server side conversions: to hash or not to hash user data?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, hash, facebook-opengraph

I'm studying this documentation:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/conversions-api/using-the-api

It says:

> Hashing
>
> Please check our customer information parameters page to see which
> parameters should be hashed before they are sent to Facebook. **If you
> are using one of our Business SDKs, the hashing is done for you by the
> SDK.**

However, the Python code example, which uses the Business SDK, provides already hashed data:

```
from facebook_business.adobjects.adspixel import AdsPixel
from facebook_business.api import FacebookAdsApi

access_token = '<ACCESS_TOKEN>'
app_secret = '<APP_SECRET>'
app_id = '<APP_ID>'
id = '<ADS_PIXEL_ID>'
FacebookAdsApi.init(access_token=access_token)

fields = [
]
params = {
  'data': [{'event_name':'PageView','event_time':1603429918,'user_data':{'fbc':'fb.1.1554763741205.AbCdEfGhIjKlMnOpQrStUvWxYz1234567890','fbp':'fb.1.1558571054389.1098115397','em':'309a0a5c3e211326ae75ca18196d301a9bdbd1a882a4d2569511033da23f0abd'}}],
}
print AdsPixel(id).create_event(
  fields=fields,
  params=params,
)
```

In particular, I'm referring to the `'em'` field (which should be an email):

```
'em':'309a0a5c3e211326ae75ca18196d301a9bdbd1a882a4d2569511033da23f0abd'
```

So, if I use `facebook_business.adobjects.adspixel.AdsPixel` should I hash the customer data? Or does it do that automatically for me?

If not, how can I do that in Python? There are many different hashing methods and functions: which is the one expected by Facebook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
import hashlib
from facebook_business.api import FacebookAdsApi
from facebook_business.adobjects.adspixel import AdsPixel

FacebookAdsApi.init(access_token=FACEBOOK_PIXEL_TOKEN)

params = {
    data: [
        "event_name": "CompleteRegistration",
        "event_time": int(datetime.now().timestamp()),
        "user_data": {
            "em": hashlib.sha256(email.encode("utf-8")).hexdigest()
        }
    ],
    "test_event_code": "TEST9876",
}
AdsPixel(FACEBOOK_PIXEL_ID).create_event(fields=[], params=params)
```

HTH

Comment: How can we verify hashed data in facebook event manager that we are sending correct details. As these details are hashed how we can use these details for facebook ad campaigns.